# Convergence in multilevel SEM in MPLus / N = 18000 about 30 clusters

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mplus

The current model we are working on is a multilevel SEM model with an 18-item scale (Mplus, ML estimation), between-level (the country-level) is saturated by letting each item correlate with one another. At the within-level, we've specified a six-factor structure (3 items per factor) and fixed variances for each factor at 1. The model seems to provide the correct kind of output, and fit indices look alright but show errors (a saddle point or a point where observed and expected information matrices do not match has been reached). There were some huge modification indices in the output. Based on these, we tried correlating the item residuals within factors. But this did not help with the convergence issues. Do you have any idea how to address convergence issues here?

The dataset is refers to N = 18000 and about 30 clusters.

Answer (score 1):

Your Level-2 $N=30$ is too small to reliably estimate a covariance matrix among 18 items (i.e., $18*19/2 = 171 unique (co)variances among country-level intercepts).  If your items are designed to measure constructs that are characteristics of the Level-1 units, you can still expect the factor scores to have random intercepts across clusters (and have ICCs), just like the items themselves do.  Fitting an overparameterized between-level model can frequently lead to convergence problems.

https://doi.org/10.1080/10705511.2018.1534205

https://doi.org/10.3390/psych3020012

Even fitting the same factor structure at Level 2 will be overparameterized for such a small sample of countries, unless you specify equality constraints that are consistent with your hypothesized factor structure and the clustered structure of the data.  Specifically, metric/"weak" invariance across clusters implies that the factor loadings are equal across levels, and scalar/"strong" invariance across clusters implies that the Level-2 residual variances are zero.

https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2017.01640

Fitting a model with these constraints will reduce the overparameterization at Level 2 because the loadings are also informed by your huge Level-1 *N* = 18K. Thus, the only parameters to estimate at Level 2 will be the $6*7/2=21$ factor (co)variances.  However, 21 is still a lot of parameters relative to 30 countries, so I imagine the *SE*s will be quite large if it does converge.  Modification indices can be used to test the cross-level equality constraints on loadings, or to test the $H_0$ that Level-2 residual variances = 0.  As the open-access publications linked above explain, freeing a residual variance implies partial scalar invariance across clusters, but unequal loadings across levels is difficult to interpret.